# Deeper reasons why solutions to equations like $\alpha^{ax^2 + bx + c} = \beta^{dx^2 + fx + g}$ form hyperbolas?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, conic-sections

I am interested if there are any "deeper reasons" why the roots of equations of the form

$$
\alpha^{ax^2 + bx + c} = \beta^{dx^2 + fx + g}
$$

form hyperbolas on the complex plane. I've managed to prove that it is true using algebra, but want to know if there is any reason aside from a purely algebraic one that this must be true. I am comfortable with the possibility that there's no nice explanation for why and that I'm just searching for meaning where there is none, but as I've yet to study university-level mathematics I was wondering if there is some connection between the topics that I'm yet to learn about.

For some context, I recently had to solve $27^{x^2 - 5} = 9^{2x}$ and came up with the general formula for the roots:

$$
x = \frac{2}{3} \pm \frac{\sqrt{49 + \frac{6\pi i n}{\ln 3}}}{3}
$$

for any integer $n$. Out of interest I tried plotting this curve for different values of $n$ and got this shape:

[image: roots of equation on Argand diagram]

This looks like a hyperbola with the two vertices centered around the two real roots, $3$ and $-5/3$! To prove this, I wrote $x = p + qi$ and then expanded the exponent like so:

$$
\begin{aligned}
27^{x^2 - 5} &= 9^{2x} \\
27^{(p + qi)^2 - 5} &= 9^{2(p + qi)} \\
27^{(p^2 - q^2) + 2pqi - 5} &= 9^{2p + 2qi} \\
e^{\ln(27) ((p^2 - q^2) + 2pqi - 5)} &= e^{\ln(9) (2p + 2qi)} \\
e^{\ln(27) ((p^2 - q^2) + 2pqi - 5) - \ln(9) (2p + 2qi)} &= 1 \\
\ln(27)((p^2 - q^2) + 2pqi - 5) - \ln(9) (2p + 2qi) &= 2\pi i n
\end{aligned}
$$

Equating real and imaginary parts gives:

$$
\ln(27)(p^2 - q^2 - 5) - 2\ln(9)p = 0 \\
2\ln(27)pqi - 2\ln(9)qi = 2\pi i n
$$

This can be further rearranged to show that all the roots lie at the intersection of one hyperbola and an infinite family of additional hyperbolas at right angles to the initial one:

$$
\left(p-\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 - q^2 = \frac{49}{9} \\ 
\left(p-\frac{2}{3}\right)q = \frac{\pi n}{\ln(27)}
$$

Here is a plot of the above two curves. The red hyperbola represents the first equation and the light green hyperbolas represent the infinite family specified by the second equation:

[image: hyperbolas]

A similar argument can be made for any equation $\alpha^{ax^2 + bx + c} = \beta^{dx^2 + fx + g}$, and for the case $e^{x^2 - 1} = 1$ then the roots all lie on the unit hyperbola, $x^2 - y^2 = 1$.

Another method of proof is to show that separating the function for the roots in terms of the parameter $n$ into a function for the real and imaginary part of the $x$  satisfies the equation $\frac{(\Re(x) - j)^2}{k} - \frac{\Im(x)^2}{l} = 1$ for some arbitrary constants $j$, $k$ and $l$.

Again, my question is: are there any "deeper reasons" that this is true? Is there a connection between roots to exponential equations like this and conic sections? Or even, is there a geometrical argument that can be made here? Or is it that this algebraic relationship *is* the connection between the two, and that I'm looking for meaning when there actually is none.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: In general, what sort of reason that a graph is a hyperbola would you consider "deeper" than an algebraic verification? Even for a simple equation like $y^2=x^2+1$, what sort of reason would be "deeper"?

Comment: For $27^{x^2-5} = 9^{2x}$ why not just do $\log_3 (27^{x^2-5})= (x^2-5)\log_3(27)=3x^2-15$ and the rhs is likewise $4x$ so $3x^2-4x -15=0$?

Comment: Perhaps adding to the points above. Note
$$ e^{(ax^2 + bx + c)\ln \alpha} = e^{(dx^2 + ex + f) \ln \beta} $$
implies that we may just redefine our coefficients and are effectively solving
$$ ax^2 + bx + c = 0. $$

Comment: @Gregory That is much easier. I was trying to include complex solutions but this would just mean solving $ax^2 + bx + c = 2\pi i n$ which is still much more concise

Comment: Ignoring complex numbers, changing the base in an exponential expression is equivalent to keeping the same base and multiplying the exponent by a constant. Specifically, assuming $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive real numbers neither equal to $1,$ we have ${\alpha}^u = {\beta}^v = {\alpha}^{\left(\frac{\ln \beta}{\ln \alpha}\right)v},$ which implies $u = \left(\frac{\ln \beta}{\ln \alpha}\right)v.$ Hence, if $u$ and $v$ are quadratic polynomials in $x$ and $y,$ then we get an equation of the form $({\text{quad}})=({\text {const}}\cdot{\text {quad}}),$ which is an at-most-quadratic equation.

Comment: After posting my comment I realized that my observation is essentially the same observation that @Gregory made.